# Send data with sockets

Tags: sockets, micropython

I have 2 ESP8266 connected in wifi.
The client sends its local time

```
def heure():
    annee = str(time.localtime()[0])
    mois = str(time.localtime()[1])
    jour = str(time.localtime()[2])
    hours = str(time.localtime()[3])
    mins = str(time.localtime()[4])
    if int(mins) < 10:
        mins = '0' + mins
    timestr = annee + ':' + mois + ':' + jour +':' +hours + ':' + mins 
    return(timestr)
def emission(donnees):
    adresse_serveur=socket.getaddrinfo("192.168.144.2",800)[0][-1]
    com_net=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    com_net.connect(adresse_serveur)
    com_net.send(donnees)
    com_net.close()

timestr=heure()
donnees=str(timestr)
emission(donnees)
```

print (donnees) --->  2023:2:1:18:08

**On the server:**

```
new_list=[]
conn, addr = s.accept()
reception_donnees=conn.recv(512)
   for item in reception_donnees.split(b':'):
      new_list.append(item.decode('ascii'))
      conn.close()
```

print (new_list) ---> ['2000', '1', '1', '0', '00'] ???
I see that the client sends 2023 and the server shows 2000
Where is the error?

I searched the web but couldn't find anything

Comment: Only one possible error: you are not printing the same thing you're sending. I don't think the problem has anything to do with sockets. See how the format is correct. The data is not getting messed up by the sockets - the client really is sending the wrong time.

Comment: you said there are two clients. Is it possible one has the correct time and one doesn't?

Comment: I checked by doing a print (data) just before the com_net.send(data) and the values are good!! I have only a client and a server

Comment: well, you are doing something wrong because the wrong data is being sent. The network is not making this problem.

Comment: I agree with you but I don't see what path I can follow.

Comment: figure out why your program is sending the wrong data.

Comment: What is curious is that I also send other data like temperature and humidity in the same message and this datas are good when received. I didn't include them in the code for clarity. The problem is with the date/time format.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the format. The program is simply sending the wrong date and time. Probably because it doesn't know what the date and time is.